# Would a full plastic gun work?

Tags: weapons, materials, firearms

So a pretty simple question. Excusing and firing springs/pins and the propellant and primer. The gun must be able to work for at least 100-200 rounds without destroying itself. Could a make a gun fully out of plastic?? What kind of plastic should if it would work?

Comment: Why all the down votes??? Perfectly good question that has answers

Comment: There are actual real-life existence of plastic guns. I don't see any evidence of research in this question.

Comment: Something I recalled that is not directly related but interesting nonetheless: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wooden_cannon .   Not something I would care to be around when it fires, particularly the rope-reinforced versions.

Comment: @VLAZ You might do your research, too.  Existing plastic guns last a few dozen shots with a steel barrel liner, one or two shots (or none -- sorry about those fingers, guy!) without.  Plastic AR receivers are lower only; the upper is metal.  A GLOCK has steel rails, barrel, springs, striker, sear, and trigger, plus the pusher and spring in the magazine (and floor plate, as I recall).

Comment: @ZeissIkon that's not my research to do, it's the question author's. I don't really feel like a personal research assistant for free. If there are *existing real world things* that fit the question, I'd expect them mentioned *in the question*. If there are problems with those real world things they should also be in the question. The downvote arrow description says "does not show any research effort" - if you feel it *does* show it, then don't click it. I'm on the opinion it *doesn't*.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with making an all-plastic gun to use anything resembling conventional ammunition (say, polymer-cased rounds) is material strength.

As far as I'm aware, there are no plastics available that can withstand momentary stresses due to 25,000 to 40,000 psi (appr. 1800 to 2700 bar) from firing a round.

Now, if one could obtain carbon nanotube fiber in long lengths, it might be possible to build a barrel as a Composite Overwrap Pressure Vessel (like what Falcon 9 uses for its propellant and pressurant tanks) that could take a momentary pressure equivalent to firing a low powered pistol cartridge -- but durability of such a barrel is a wild guess.

Beyond that, there are other high stress parts in a gun that aren't amenable to the composite overwrap -- locking lugs in a semi-automatic action, for instance.

You'd be building your plastic gun out of handwavium -- postulating a plastic that doesn't exist, one that can do what no existing plastic can.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [it can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_printed_firearms) [be made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberator_(gun))

> In 2012, the U.S.-based team Defense Distributed disclosed plans to design a working plastic gun that could be downloaded and reproduced by anybody with a 3D printer. Defense Distributed has also designed a 3D printable AR-15 type rifle lower receiver (capable of lasting more than 650 rounds) and a variety of magazines.

Comment: It would be better to link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberator_(gun) which is the all-plastic actual Defense Distributed firearm in question.  The mention of the all-plastic AR-15 lower receiver isn't relevant since the upper receiver & barrel still must be metal.

Comment: Even the Liberator linked in the comment above uses a metal barrel liner.  See my answer -- there is no plastic currently available that can stand the stress of even a relatively low power round for more than one or two shots without metal in the chamber and barrel.

Comment: @ZeissIkon  I was under the impression that barrel liner was optional if a one-shot lifespan was acceptable?   Kind of makes one wonder if a brass shotgun shell (about half the barrel pressure of the .380 ACP round used in the Liberator) would work more reliably.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Shotgun is half the pressure on five or ten times the area.  It's much worse.  You'd be better shooting .22 LR from the same barrel O.D.  Single shot lifetime implies a willingness to accept a possible barrel burst, too -- not for me, thanks.